Angular Frontend Cors
I want to upload an xlsx file from google drive or any other website and open it in my application (x-data-spreadsheet).
The issue is, when I try to upload the file I get a CORS error:
"Access to fetch at 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1T-gTh7BpKf2hLMhZOq_lwvHTgcw80hxI' from origin 'http://localhost:4203' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled."

This is my code in the frontend ts file:
loadExcelFile() {
                           
    const excelFileUrl = "https://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&id=1T-gTh7BpKf2hLMhZOq_lwvHTgcw80hxI"; // Replace with actual URL
    fetch(excelFileUrl)
        .then(response => response.arrayBuffer())
        .then(data => {
            const workbook = XLSX.read(data, { type: 'array' });
            const sheetName = workbook.SheetNames[0];
            const worksheet = workbook.Sheets[sheetName];
            const json = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet);

            console.log("LoadExcel from URL :" ,json); // Output parsed data to the console (or bind it to a table in the UI)
            this.dataLoad = json;
            const data55 = this.exportToExcel();
            const data555 = this.gridData_workbook_to(data55);
            this.spreadsheet.loadData(data555);
        
          });
    }

I tried a proxy config with both names, localhost and googledrive or the name of any website but nothing happens.

You should use Google Drive API. Google Drive doesn't allow you to access the file you are trying to get, the way you are trying. It is not an Angular Issue.
